# Python Convert time to UTC format

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone

```
from django.utils import timezone
time_zone = timezone.get_current_timezone_name() # Gives 'Asia/Kolkata'
date_time = datetime.time(12,30,tzinfo=pytz.timezone(str(time_zone)))
```

Now I need to convert this time to UTC format and save it in Django model. I am not able to use `date_time.astimezone(pytz.timezone('UTC'))`. How can I convert the time to UTC. Also Back to 'time_zone'.

This is a use case when user type time in a text box and we need to save time time in UTC  format. Each user will also select his own time zone that we provide from Django `timezone` module.

Once the user request back the saved time it must be shown back to him in his selected time zone.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

These things are always easier using complete `datetime` objects, e.g.:

```
import datetime
import pytz

time_zone = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')

# get naive date
date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
# get naive time
time = datetime.time(12, 30)
# combite to datetime
date_time = datetime.datetime.combine(date, time)
# make time zone aware
date_time = time_zone.localize(date_time)

# convert to UTC
utc_date_time = date_time.astimezone(pytz.utc)
# get time
utc_time = utc_date_time.time()

print(date_time)
print(utc_date_time)
print(utc_time)
```

Yields:

```
2014-07-13 12:30:00+05:30
2014-07-13 07:00:00+00:00
07:00:00
```

right now for me.

Comment: It shows `+5:53:00` when it has not yet been applied to a `datetime`, because that's the earliest representation in the tzdb.  The local mean time is usually calculated from solar observation, which reasonable aligns these old dates to our modern system.

Comment: Also, you should use `localize` instead of assigning the time zone to `tzinfo` directly.  Read about `localize` in [the pytz docs](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @MattJohnson Thanks for feedback and +5:53 explanation! True that about `localize`. Updated the answer accordingly, now this is what we wanted.

Answer (score 0):

set the timezone to UTC in your settings.py. Get the user input of time and timezone in certain format. Suppose you get the user time as 'Jul-7-2014 12:35PM:30' (consider using date input in your html).

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

// convert the time to standard format
user_date = datetime.strptime('Jul-7-2014 12:35PM:30', '%b-%d-%Y %I:%M%p:%S')
user_date_string = user_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
// save the time to model with users timezone

// now when user asks back for his time, add the timezone with timedelta
user_date = datetime.strptime(user_date_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
user_date = user_date + timedelta(hours = 5, minutes = 30)
// finally display it
print user_data.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

*this is not considering django inbuild datetime functions which returns datetime object for datetime model field. If implemented that it will be more simple